# Help understand this solution/Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, approximation

Good day everyone. In this [appendix](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/r.perman/Appendix_15_2.pdf), particularly this [part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwwRo.png), the author approximated $1-aR$ with $e^h$ where $h=2.5$. Can anyone explain to me how did the author get this outcome? Variable $a$ is a parameter while $R$ is a real positive number.

I found myself with a similar expression looking like

$$Fe^{(-aR)}(1 + a -aR)$$

And I would like to attempt a similar "trick" to get rid of the $R$ in $-aR$ just like they did. Any help please?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the approximation for $e^{-x}$ from its taylor expansion series $e^{-x}\approx 1-x$, but that is only valid for small values of $x$

Comment: Thank you. I tried with the lambert function but I couldn't get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation, as written in the appendix being
$$M\Pi_t=K(1-a R_t)\,e^{-a R_t}$$ rewrite it as
$$e^{-a R_t}=-\frac {M\Pi_t } {aK }\frac 1 { R_t-\frac 1a}$$and the solution is given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).